# Ionic Angular Firestore : Array indexing incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I'm messing around with firestore just to get the basics down. However, I am having issues reading my data (as an array of docs in a collection) as it is indexing in an order I can't understand. Compared to the realtime database, it was ordered based on the time it was pushed it was pushed to firebase. I understand there is implementation for indexing in firestore now, which is why I created a "timeCreated" timestamp in my fields of my documents.

the problem: trying to read chronologically data as it was pushed to firestore, and display it in same order in hmtl. Shows in weird order

Still learning so the issue is probably more apparent than I realize, thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <ion-input placeholder = "Your name" [(ngModel)] = "name" >  </ion-input>
 <ion-input placeholder = "Your age" [(ngModel)] = "age" >  </ion-input>
 <ion-input placeholder = "Your sex" [(ngModel)] = "sex" >  </ion-input>
 <ion-input placeholder = "Your race" [(ngModel)] = "race" >  </ion-input>

 <button ion-button (click) = "submit()"> Submit </button>
 <br>
 <button ion-button (click) = "peek()"> Peek </button>
 <br>
 <button ion-button (click) = "load()"> Load </button>

 <ion-item *ngFor = "let person of people">
  <h3> {{person.name}} </h3>
  <p> Age: {{person.age}}</p>
  <p> Sex: {{person.sex}}</p>
  <p> Race: {{ person.race }}</p>
 </ion-item>


</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public name: string;
  public age: string;
  public sex: string;
  public race: string;
  public db;
  public colRef;
  public docRef;
  public people: Array<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.db = firebase.firestore(); 
    this.colRef = this.db.collection("people");
  }

  submit(){
    this.db.collection("people").add({
      name: this.name,
      age: this.age,
      sex: this.sex,
      race: this.race,
      timeCreated: new Date().getTime()
    }).then(cont => {
      alert("Data uploaded!");
      this.name = "";
      this.age = "";
      this.sex = "";
      this.race = "";
    });
  }

  peek(){
    alert("Name: "+ this.name);
  }

  load(){
    this.colRef.get().then( snapshot => {
      this.people = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var data = doc.data();
        this.people.push({
          id: doc.key,
          name: data.name,
          age: data.age,
          sex: data.sex,
          race: data.race,
          timeCreated: data.timeCreated
        });
      });
      console.log(this.people);

    });
  }
}
```

**Firestore data structure:**
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVedD.png)

**In-app data display/order:**
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqKDr.png)

**Console log of array of data retrieved from firestore:**
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV77E.png)

Comment: I understand I could re-sort it after finishing the pushes to my array in the TS, but I'd rather not just bc conceptually I shouldn't even have to to begin with.

Comment: just run your query then check your log. Firestore will provide you with a `click here` to create index response, i.e., just follow the instructions

Comment: @RonRoyston I guess ordering the indexes in-console wasn't enough. So when referencing the collection I need to also add orderBy("timeCreated", "asc") which seems a little weird but whatever.